# Data id not deleted when ajax successfully completed

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to delete from database using jQuery ajax function in CI when I click the button data deleted successfully but when ajax request is completed the element is not deleted.

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger del_comment" data-id="<?php echo $report->video_comment_id; ?>" data-action="<?php echo site_url('admin/delete_comment') ?>">
            Delted Comment
        </a>
    </td>
```

here is my jQuery code

```
$('.del_comment').click(function(){
    var comment_report = $(this).data('id');

             $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).data('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        comment_report:comment_report
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        if (true)
                         {
                            $("a[data-id='" + comment_report + "']").find('td').remove();
                         } 
                         else{

                         };

                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert('somthing worong..')

                    }
            });//ajax ends here                     

});
```

I am not giving you controller and model because all things working correctly.

I want to delete `<td>` when ajax, how can I do so?

Comment: try $(this).parent(td).remove();?

Comment: its not working i want  to delete tr but this code is working $("a[data-id='" + comment_report + "']").parent('td').remove()

Comment: i want to delete tr when i put .parent('tr').remove() its not working i don't know why..

Comment: see jsfiddle below. when u click on the anchor it removes the closest 'tr'..

Comment: you can use @Awena solution.It must work.If u still facing problem give id(combine with video_comment_id) to the tr and delete it

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`

https://jsfiddle.net/m42bavqj/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[data-id='" + comment_report + "']").find('td').remove()
```

The above is finding a child TD when it should be finding the parent TD.

```
$("a[data-id='" + comment_report + "']").parent('td').remove()
```